# Get tags of content on same page

Tags: java, tags, liferay, portlet

I am developing portlet for liferay portal. I need in my portlet to get tags of content in other portlet. All i have at this moment is portlet IDs of oll portlets on the page. For example, if I have portlet with ID 33 (blog) I need to get tags of blog entry? opened in blog portlet. Any ideas? Thatnks fore future answers!

Comment: Let me see if I have understood your questions correctly: Do u want to display only those `tags` in your custom-portlet that are added to all the Blog entries displayed in the blogs portlet in the page? Like this if there are documents, Wiki, web-content etc portlets on the page then you need to display `tags` that are added to contents of all these portlets? Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I have found good solution:
I have writed hook-plugin for blog portlet.In this plugin I modify init-ext.jsp, where I add AssetEntry object to shared session parametres. In my custom portlet I just take this parameter and can use it in any way. The problem Im thinking about at this moment is the order of portlet execution. The order is not specified, so I can't be shure, that blog executes first and in my custom portlet I would be abl to access AssetEntry in public session parametres. Anyway it is working solution.